# Correct usage of a counter using arcpy.da.UpdateCursor

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1

In the Python code inside a `Calculate Value` tool in my model, I have the following:

```
getNum("%Selected Features%")
```

---

```
def getNum(ftr):
  lst = [4, 11, 15] #values for SQL expression
  x = 20
  fields = ('TYPE_A', 'TYPE_B', 'NUM_ID')
  for l in lst:
    y = x + 1
    whereclause = """"NUM_ID" = %s """ % l
    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(ftr, fields, whereclause) as cursor:
      for row in cursor:
        if row[0] ! = row[1]:
          row[2] = y
        cursor.updateRow(row)
    y += 1
```

What I would like to do is, for every element in `lst`, create a cursor based on a selection of records where `NUM_ID = l`. The values in `TYPE_A` and `TYPE_B` should be compared for each record and updated if necessary.

The script is failing after the cursor is created, with the error `Item not in collection`. If I remove the `whereclause`, it executes. Once the records have been selected and the values compared and updated if necessary, I need to increment the counter `y` by 1. I think I'm doing it in the wrong place though, because if I run the script without the `whereclause` it does execute correctly.When I check the records with the changed values, they are now all set to `y`, which indicates that `y` was not incremented.

Comment: Try stepping through your code in a Python debugger to get an idea of what's going on.

Comment: Is n defined somewhere else? cant see it in the code you posted.

Comment: @dango sorry was a typo, changed it to `y`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couple of points that might help:

- You redefine the value of `y` at the beginning of your for loop, so every time the loop is executed `y` is reset to `x + 1`. Instead set `y` outside the loop:

```py
y = x + 1
for l in lst:
    #...
```

- Depending on the type of feature class you're using ArcGIS requires different delimiters around field names. For example, `[PERSONAL_GDB]` vs `"FILE_GDB"`. To prevent having to worry about this you can use the [`AddFieldDelimiters`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/AddFieldDelimiters/018v0000006p000000/) arcpy function to get back the correctly delimited fields.

```py
#Using dictionary string-formatting
whereclause = "%(sql_name)s = %(l)i """ % {"sql_name":arcpy.AddFieldDelimiters(ftr, "NUM_ID"), "l":l}
```

- Lastly you should probably check that `NUM_ID` exists in your feature class as otherwise the cursor will fall over. You can use [`ListFields`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v00000012000000) for this.

```py
assert "NUM_ID" in [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(ftr)], "NUM_ID field no in feature class"
```

Comment: I think the field assertion check is probably a little overly defensive, but that's just me. I would expect arcpy to generate a reasonable error message on its own about this.

Comment: @blah238 You're right, it should - this is more sa an example of a way you *could* check. Also, cheers for the props!

Comment: Thanks for all the tips. After changing the `whereclause`, it failed because it was expecting an integer but I'm actually testing for a string, so I changed it to `%(l)s` so it's fine. It now fails on the fact that is an invalid sql statement.

Comment: The counter now increments correctly and the field values are updated as expected. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @om_henners great suggestions, it seems to me like you could use an `IN` statement to reduce the number of queries to the database from `len(lst)` to 1. I have an example function to build such a WHERE clause in this answer: [Select features by attribute if in Python list](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/29745/753)

Comment: Thanks for the link to your other answer, it solved the issue I had in the comment I made above.