# Invalid expression in SelectLayerByAttribute?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I am coping with a shapefile and I want to select some rows if the values in one column are in a Python list. The following gives the code I write:

```
tpu_involved = list(set(dataframe['SmallTPU']))
selection_expression = '"SmallTPU" IN ({0})'.format(', '.join(map(str, tpu_involved)) or 'NULL')
print('---------------------------------------------------------------')
print('The invalid expression is: {}'.format(selection_expression))
print('---------------------------------------------------------------')
selected_layer = arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(in_layer_or_view='tpu_lyr',
                                                                 selection_type='NEW_SELECTION',
                                                                 where_clause=selection_expression)
```

The `tpu_lyr` is the layer which is loaded from a local shapefile. I have checked some previous questions like [Selecting features by attribute if in Python list?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/29735), but it still does not work.

Comment: try `'"SmallTPU" IN ({0}) OR "SmallTPU" IS NULL'.format(...`

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply! Finally, I use the following codes:
```Python
tpu_list = list(dataframe['SmallTPU'])
        tpu_changed = tuple([item.encode('utf-8') for item in tpu_list])
        selection_expression = """ "SmallTPU" IN {} """.format(tpu_changed)
```
You need to encode the string first...

Comment: Nice, you can post that as an answer to your own question