# Python problems with select by attributes and user input

Tags: arcpy, census, select-by-attribute, density, population

I am attempting to create a tool where the user can input a census tract number within the city of Plano (there are 77 tracts) and it ultimately creates a map layout showing the population density. I am having problems using the select tool to copy the inputed tract layer into a new feature class.

It is executing successfully but it keeps copying the original plano_tract layer into a new feature class instead of copying the selected tract that was inputed. Not sure if I needed a where clause in the script or if I could simply just do a select by attribute function.

I was using this thread as reference but it I still getting the same result.

[Python Script for Select by Attributes taking user input](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/35117/python-script-for-select-by-attributes-taking-user-input)

I am pretty new to Python and this is a beginner exercise for me.

Here is my script:

```
import arcpy
import os
from arcpy import env

#set workspace
Workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

env.workspace = r"C:\Users\dallascowboy83\Desktop\project 2\project\project.gdb"
env.overwriteOutput = 1

#set local variables
tracts = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

#ask user for tract to search
tract = raw_input("Please type Tract Number: ")

plano_tract = r"C:\Users\dallascowboy83\Desktop\project 2\project\project.gdb\plano_tract.shp"

plano_tract_lyr = "plano_tract_lyr"

#user selects tract, Select by Attribute tool runs
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("plano_tract", "plano_tract_lyr")

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("plano_tract_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", "\"Tract_Number\" = "+ tract)

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("plano_tract", "plano_tract_feat")

#add field
arcpy.AddField_management("plano_tract_feat", "density", "DOUBLE")

#calculate field
arcpy.CalculateField_management("plano_tract_select", "density", "[DP0010001] / [sq_mile_1]", "PYTHON", "")

print "executed successfully"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Select Layer by Attribute tool applies a selection to a layer. However, your Copy Features tool is copying the entire `"plano_tract"` dataset, and not the "`plano_tract_lyr"` layer which has the selection applied. Here's the revised code:

```
#user selects tract, Select by Attribute tool runs
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("plano_tract", "plano_tract_lyr")

arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("plano_tract_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", "\"Tract_Number\" = "+ tract)

arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("plano_tract_lyr", "plano_tract_feat")
```

To zoom to selected features and export to JPEG:

```
#Current map document
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")

#Assumes only one data frame
arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0].zoomToSelectedFeatures()

#Export 
arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, "Output.jpg")
```

Comment: Thank you so much dmahr! I knew I slipped up in my code somewhere. By any chance, did you know how I could zoom in on that new selected tract layer and then export it to a JPEG using arcpy.mapping?

Comment: @Victor I added some code above for the zoom and export. You may need to turn of selection highlighting, otherwise the exported layer will have the (by default) cyan borders around selected features. If you're happy with this answer, you should mark it as answered.