# Export Features by Multivalue?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, feature-extraction, multi-values, user-interface

I have a similar problem to the user in this question from a couple of years ago:

[How to Extract by Attribute Using ModelBuilder with User Input?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21760/how-to-extract-by-attribute-using-modelbuilder-with-user-input)

Except when I go to build the model, the "Values" variable does not exist in the dropdown. Is there a newer way to do this now?

I have, essentially, a parcel layer that I want the user to input the digits of each parcel they want to extract and then export that to a new layer.

In the past, I just built the SQL in Excel and copied that into the Query Builder and then exported the data from there. However, I want to create this tool that a few of my less computer-oriented coworkers can use so it eliminates third party (ie Excel) software.

If anybody has any suggestions I'm open to them all!